# Target cannot be null

Tags: android, event-handling

I am using `EventBus` library for event handling in `Android`.
But as I caught the event at function `onEvent(Object obj)`, it gives the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
```

My code:

```
public void onEvent(Object obj) {
    String file = storeUserPhoto(obj.getUserId(), obj.getImage());
    Picasso.with(activity).load(new File(file)).into(imageView);
}
```

I understand the problem but don't know how to resolve it.

I checked the view `ImageView` value and its `null`.

Comment: did u checked if imageView is `null`? is imageView in layout file or initialised programmatically?

Comment: yes, i have initialized the ImageView programmatically.

Comment: Simply put this is a null pointer exception set a breakpoint on line Picasso.w... and check which one of the three variables is null!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `EventBus'th` problem. This error is thrown by `Picasso` if you pass a `null`-object to the `.into(imageView);` method. Here the `imageView` is a *target*, which is null at the moment you use it.

Comment: Does not suggest anything new.. OP already knows this.. please the read the full question..

Comment: @metalurgus, its not the Picasso problem, even i wrote the line holder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(file))); i get the simillar error..